# What song did you sing or what song have you sung?

Tags: usage

Suppose there was a festival this weekend and today is beginning of hte next week, do i ask "What song did you sing at the festival" or "What song have you sung at the festival?"What if it's one month after the festival? If it's a year or more after the festival it'd be simple past but this recent past thing makes things a bit complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would it ever be *have*?

Comment: Present perfect does *not* mean "recent past",

Comment: Even after a year, you might ask a friend what songs worked in the past. You might be suggesting repeating them, using similar genres, or taking a fresh approach: "What songs have you sung at the festival in past years?"

Comment: Rule of thumb: use simple past tense wherever it can be used grammatically **and** without sounding awkward. That **keeps things simple!**

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar, but to me the two questions have different meanings.  The first refers to a specific performance, presumably (without further context) the most recent one.  _What [specific] song did you sing at the festival [last weekend]?_ is different from _[Generally speaking,] What song[s] have you sung at the festival [in the past]?_

Comment: Which song you sang last week.or. Do you remember the song I had sung for the festival?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct (although plural is needed for "have sung, imo), but I would use them in different contexts.

> **A** : Last night at the karaoke bar, I did so well that people stood up and cheered me on.
>   **B** : What song did you sing?

B is asking the *specific* song that A was singing when they cheered him on.

> **A** : I used to hang out at the karaoke bar all the time. I must have gone through the entire songbook.
>   **B** : What songs have you sung?

B is asking for a *list* of songs that A has sung over a long period of time, he's not asking about a specific instance.